# escaping a " in NVelocity

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, view, castle, nvelocity

how can I escape " in NVelocity ?

e.g.
test.message = "136# 1/4" Test Test Test"

if I do `<input type="text" id="Test.Description" value="$test.message"/>`

it displays : 136# 1/4

if I do `<input type="text" id="Test.Description" value=$test.message/>`

it displays : 136

if I do `<input type="text" id="Test.Description" value='$test.message'/>`

it displays : 136# 1/4" Test Test Test but it escapes '

how can I display 136# 1/4" Test Test Test without escaping anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nVelocity, at this time, has no built-in facility for HTML-encoding it's variables (there has been some talk about adding it in a future version)

In the meantime, in your controller, you'll just need to do:

```
test.message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(test.message);
```

or

```
test.message = test.message.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
```